# Xamarin.Forms: Can I embed one ContentPage or ContentView into another ContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, content-pages

I have multiple ContentPage xaml files in my Xamarin project. I want to embed a shared piece of xaml into each ContentPage.  There is nothing particularly special about the shared piece of xaml (it does't need to do anything platform specific). Shouldn't it be just as easy as embedding a tag in the xaml of the ContentPage to include the shared xaml file? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can take the parent child of your `ContentPage` (for example, a *StackLayout* that wraps all the children), put it in an external xaml file,
and then include that component in each one of your ContentPages.

The external xaml file will be a **StackLayout** type, rather than a ContentPage.

**Edit** - added a code sample:

Let's add a header StackLayout: we add a code behind class:

```cs
public partial class HeaderNavigationBar 
{
    public HeaderNavigationBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then add the XAML code:

```xml
<StackLayout x:Class="HeaderNavigationBar"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Padding="10"
             BackgroundColor="White">

    <Image Source="burger_icon"
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
           Aspect="AspectFit">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SlideNavigationDrawerCommand}" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</StackLayout>
```

And finally, in the page where you want to reuse your component - add this reference:`<HeaderNavigationBar />`.

Comment: Thank you. That will get me closer. Can you tell me what the syntax is for including that external xaml file into my content pages?

Comment: Getting closer. When I try to run that, it gives me this error in the xaml file: "x is undeclared namespace." Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to add to the Content Page header decelerations something like this: xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Consumer.Mobile.Views.Common;assembly=Consumer.Mobile" and then declare your reference like this:
 <common:HeaderNavigationBar></common:HeaderNavigationBar>

Comment: Still no luck. The contentpage errors out with "Type common:HeaderNavigation not found in xmlns clr-namespace..." etc.

Comment: Is there no official documentation on this anywhere?

Comment: Common is the namespace of the folder I have placed the header navigation bar. You should replace it with your namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to get it to work cross-platform as long as the XAML and code-behind files are in a Portable Class Library. Sadly in my case I was using a Shared Project so that I could also use Parse.com libraries in a shared scenario. If I move my Xamarin Forms code-behinds to a Portable Class Library, then that will break my Parse code since there's not a version of Parse available for PCL yet, that I know of. Anyway, thank you very much for the help in figuring out how to include a contentview into a contentpage!

Answer (score 19):

Thank you very much IdoT, It did work for me, but after adding some lines.
As this will help in making templates/custom controls/sub forms, easily added/shared across Xamarin.Forms.

Here is my full work based on your suggestion, so it can be used as is with others:

**HeaderNavigationBar.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App9.MVC.Views.HeaderNavigationBar"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Padding="10"
             ackgroundColor="White">

    <Button Text="Internal 1" />
    <Button Text="Internal 2" />
</StackLayout>
```

As you can see, added:

```xml
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

and in the `HeaderNavigationBar.cs`, it was declared as `StackLayout`:

**HeaderNavigationBar.cs**

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App9.MVC.Views
{
    public partial class HeaderNavigationBar : StackLayout
    {
        public HeaderNavigationBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

then for the page that will hold it/show it:

**MainView.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:App9.MVC.Views;assembly=App9"
             x:Class="App9.MVC.Views.MainView">

    <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,20">
        <common:HeaderNavigationBar>
            <Button Text="External 1" />
        </common:HeaderNavigationBar>

        <Button Text="Test Button 1
                x:Name="btnPage1"
                Clicked="btnPage1_clicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can notice, the namespace has the full path, in the `MainView`:

```xml
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:App9.MVC.Views;assembly=App9"
```

Also, you can notice that there is a button called `External 1`, this will also show with the
Internal buttons, as the control is a StackLayout, so it can handle adding more controls.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Also for Page inside another Page:

- https://github.com/twintechs/TwinTechsFormsLib
- http://blog.twintechs.com/advanced-xamarin-forms-techniques-for-flexible-and-performant-cross-platform-apps-part-5-page-in-page-embedding

Again thanks goes to IdoT.