# Xamarin Forms Android: TabbedPage Font Style

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

how can I change the style of the tab title? The most important thing is, that the titles not cutted off like at the screenshot. So I have to change the size of the titles.
I started creating a Custom Renderer for tabbedpage, but I don't know how to go on.

```
Xaml:
<custom:CustomTabbedPage...

Forms:
public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedPage...

Forms.Droid
public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
```

The TabbedPage has NavigationPages with ContentPages.

If you need further information, let me know. Thank you.

[image]

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage"
        x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
<NavigationPage Title="Start" Icon="start.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:StartPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Symptom-Tagebuch" Icon="tagebuch.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:TagebuchPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
...
```

Comment: Nobody?
So all are happy with the cutted titles and nobody ever changed it. Can't believe this. ;)

Comment: Could you please show some code, how did you create each item for `TabbedPage`? I used its `ItemTemplate` to build the source collection of several `ContentPage`, and specify each item's title through the `Title` property of `ContentPage`, it works fine, titles are not cutted off, all styles are default, so I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT shure, I added some code from my project

Comment: Is that possible that you replace `NavigationPage` with `ContentPage`? Otherwise we may need to modify the style of `NavigationPage`.

Comment: I think I need NavigationPage because all the pages have subpages

Comment: An example how to modify the titles would be fine, I couldn't find anything :(

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT do you have an example for modifying the NavigationPage?

Comment: sorry for the late responding, I've wrote an answer to share my progress on this case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default title style of `NavigationPage` behaviors different on different size of device. By my side on 7" KitKat emulator it looks so:

[image]

and on 5" KitKat emulator it looks so:

[image]

Or it could be the version problem which cause the behavior of this `NavigationPage` by my side so different from yours, I can't reproduce yout issue. Anyway, if you want to customize the layout of your `NavigationPage`, you can create a custom render for your android platform. For more information, you can refer to the official document [Customizing Controls on Each Platform](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/), and if you're looking for a demo, there are discussions on the official forum about customize the title font of `NavigationPage` you may also take a look: [Discussion 1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22825/how-to-change-title-font-for-navigation-bar) and [Discussion 2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17278/custom-font-in-xamarin-forms-font-awesome/p1).

Another possible solution to your problem is that I think you can change the `NavigationPage` to `ContentPage`, and change your sub pages to content view, and by doing this, you can refer to [Xamarin.Forms: Can I embed one ContentPage or ContentView into another ContentPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417671/xamarin-forms-can-i-embed-one-contentpage-or-contentview-into-another-contentpa).

According to your description, maybe the first solution by creating your own custom render is more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for this, I found another solution and will post it these days

Comment: @Ralf what did you find? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the textview of title through TabLayout view children in CustomRendered and change font style

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(BottomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Daddy.Droid
{
    public class BottomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
                return;

            TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
            Android.Views.ViewGroup vgroup = (Android.Views.ViewGroup)tablayout.GetChildAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < vgroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.ViewGroup vvgroup = (Android.Views.ViewGroup)vgroup.GetChildAt(i);
                Typeface fontFace = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(this.Context.Assets, "IranSans.ttf");
                for (int j = 0; j < vvgroup.ChildCount; j++)
                {
                    Android.Views.View vView = (Android.Views.View)vvgroup.GetChildAt(j);
                    if (vView.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView) || vView.GetType() == typeof(Android.Widget.TextView))
                    {
                        //here change textview style
                        TextView txtView = (TextView)vView;                        
                        txtView.TextSize = 14f;
                        txtView.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```