# FIXED: Xamarin Forms - How do i add a back button in the navigation bar?

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to give the user the ability to go the previous page when using the app on any page. But I don't know how to go about it.

**In the XAML code:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image Margin="0,20,0,0"
         HeightRequest="25"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Source="back"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         WidthRequest="25" />
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding  Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:KlinectBaseViewModel}}, Path=BackView}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
 </Grid>
```

**CS:**

```
  public ICommand BackView => new Command(async () => await NavigationService.GoBack());
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417671/xamarin-forms-can-i-embed-one-contentpage-or-contentview-into-another-contentpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the TitleView of ContentPage as you want . For example

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <!--back to preview page-->
            <ImageButton Margin="0,20,0,0"
            Grid.Column="0"
         HeightRequest="25"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Source="back.png" 
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         WidthRequest="25" 
         Command="{Binding xxx}"/>

            <!--back to last page ,  if necerssary-->
            <ImageButton Margin="0,20,0,0"
            Grid.Column="1"
         HeightRequest="25"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Source="back.png" 
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         WidthRequest="25" 
         Command="{Binding xxx}"/>


            <!--Title Label-->
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Title" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

For more details you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar .

Comment: On the Command="{Binding xxx}" how do i tell it to send the user back to the last page?

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical .

Comment: Yes haha. I have managed to sort this out by using  public ICommand BackView => new Command(async () => await NavigationService.GoBack());

Comment: Great, only <NavigationPage.TitleView> works with Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NewPage());