# Xamarin.Forms Form.Children.Add for ContentPage

Tags: forms, xamarin, addition, children

I would like to have a few Content Pages , which I add in my MainPage class. I use SetLayout function to do that, which parameter is ContentPage. How to dock a ContentPage to my ContentPage( MainPage) as children please?
My MainPage xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.MainPage"
         x:Class="MyApp;assembly=App"
         BackgroundColor="White">
<StackLayout x:Name="Form">
</StackLayout>
```

And SetLayout function in MainPage.cs

```
private void SetLayout(ContentPage page)
    {
        if (LastControl != null)
        {
            LastControl.IsEnabled = false;
            Form.Children.Remove(LastControl);
            Form.Children.Add(page);
           
        }
        else
        {
            Form.Children.Add(page);
        }
        page.IsVisible = true;

        LastControl = page;
    }
```

In function above I have error on Form.Children.Add, because this wants contentview, not contentpage.
I dont want to change my ContentPage to ContentView, because I want to have working BackButton.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417671/xamarin-forms-can-i-embed-one-contentpage-or-contentview-into-another-contentpa

Comment: Has StackLayout BackButton method? When I click on back button this just minimalize app, no go to previous page.

Comment: If you want to use navigate function, Why not to use `   Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            Navigation.RemovePage(page);` following way to push or remove a page.

Comment: Parameter is Page, not View, so I cannot use this method.

Comment: Do you want to achieve a pop up view like this plugin result? https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: I resolved this :)

Comment: Please share your solution to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I would like to have a lot of template pages of type ContentPage and then in one ContentPage , have function to use these templates, something like this.Children.Add for ContentViews